# How can I replace(re-execute ) current script functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, eval, execute

I want to replace load script into existing script after ajax response.

Due to I will only update some element so the whole page will not be reloaded, and some event on replaced element will be lost.

[Re-Run application Javascript on ajax loaded content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742835/re-run-application-javascript-on-ajax-loaded-content) <--- This is not a solution for me...

I tried take the script tag from loaded html and `eval()` them. However, this will not replace the existing functions but double them.

I want to replace, or re-execute the script function by not use `$(document).html(data);`

I read many references such like, 
http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss2.shtml

But I dont very understand it.....

Please help and advice a more easy understanding example. Thank you very much!

My script now is

```
  $script.each(function(index){ //data from loaded page, same page
    if(!$(this).attr('src')){    //replace where is not from external only

          $(document.getElementsByTagName( 'script' )).slice(index).remove(); 
          //remove existing script, no working

         eval($(this).text()); 
         // re-execute, wokring
     }; 
 });
```

Comment: I found not exactly what you want, but maybe you can find something useful in the script source: http://www.arashkarimzadeh.com/component/content/article/17.html

Answer (score 1):

You may try to combine your logic to functions and call it when you want. Moreover, if you ajax-loaded content will contains JS functions you can call it after place retrieved html to the page.

When I need to bind events to some dynamically loaded components I implement function like following:

```
function rebindDynamic() {
  $('#elem1')
    .unbind()  //Or unbind('click') if you want to unbind specific handlers
    .click(function (e) { ... });

  $('#elem2')
    .unbind()  //Or unbind('keyup') if you want to unbind specific handlers
    .keyup(function (e) { ... });

  ...................
}
```

I hope it will helps.

Comment: I mean following: can you envelop your script to the function and re-exectute (i.e. re-call) function?

Comment: due to I am trying to creating a interface can replace anywhere, there is no way you know what events are binding in that place...