# JSONP loading of script tags?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, cross-domain, jsonp

This is a repost of something I asked earlier. But have added the fiddle of my code for clarity - [JSONP - JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ss2PR/)

```
var sTerm = "summerstyle";
fnMakeCallback();
function fnMakeCallback(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
    url:"http://54.252.155.222/~forever/index.php/hype_engine_controller/load_widget_jsonp/%23"+sTerm+"?callback=jsonpCallback",
        dataType:"jsonp",
        jsonp:"callback",
        async: false,
        crossdomain: true,
        jsonpCallback:"jsonpCallback",
        success: function(data) {
            $("#hype_engine").html(data.html);
        }
    });
}

function jsonpCallback(data){
}
```

I seem to be getting the html in data.html fine - appending this to a div. But the data.head contains a bunch of style tags. I need these files to act on the HTML I'm loading in data.html. (JS/jQuery plugins, etc) Can anyone help me in understanding how to execute these script files so they are available when I pull in the HTML via the code above...?

It doesn't seem to be loading the files as I'm getting a lot of "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'carouFredSel'" and similar. It also gives me the cross domain request error - visible on the JSLINT above -

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://54.252.155.222/~forever/assets/js/lib/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.js. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

- leading me to think it's not so simple to load scripts with sources

What am I doing wrong?!

EDIT: 
I am not loading scripts into the HEAD any more but just loading them inline - not great practice I admit but I just want it to work first -
I'm loading through codeigniter but the header view is as follows -

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?= base_url(); ?>assets/js/lib/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?= base_url(); ?>assets/js/lib/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?= base_url(); ?>assets/js/main.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://api.filepicker.io/v1/filepicker.js'></script>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Henny+Penny|Gloria+Hallelujah|Nothing+You+Could+Do|Over+the+Rainbow' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link rel='stylesheet' href='<?= base_url(); ?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'/>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='<?= base_url(); ?>assets/css/internal/main.css'/>

<script type='text/javascript' src='<?= base_url(); ?>assets/js/lib/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1-packed.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='<?= base_url(); ?>assets/js/lib/helper-plugins/jquery.mousewheel.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?= base_url(); ?>assets/js/lib/helper-plugins/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?= base_url(); ?>assets/js/lib/helper-plugins/jquery.transit.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?= base_url(); ?>assets/js/lib/helper-plugins/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.min.js'></script>


<link rel='stylesheet' href='<?= base_url(); ?>assets/js/lib/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.4' type='text/css' media='screen' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?= base_url(); ?>assets/js/lib/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.4'></script>

<link rel='stylesheet' href='<?= base_url(); ?>assets/js/lib/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5' type='text/css' media='screen' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?= base_url(); ?>assets/js/lib/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?= base_url(); ?>assets/js/lib/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.5'></script>

<link rel='stylesheet' href='<?= base_url(); ?>assets/js/lib/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7' type='text/css' media='screen' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?= base_url(); ?>assets/js/lib/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7'></script>
```

Comment: [CHECK IT OUT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742835/re-run-application-javascript-on-ajax-loaded-content)

Comment: I'm not sure this is doing what I want? Or if it is I don't understand how I am meant to apply scirpts to a page thats already loaded via the $(document).ready function...
How would delegate or live work in relation to loading scripts...?

Comment: Also - I inspect my page the <head> contains all the relavent <script> that reference an external site - but they haven't been applied it seems.

Comment: @lionysis: Can you post the contents of that `data.head`, please? It seems like you're having problems with asynchronously loading scripts.

Comment: Added ^ - Have deleted the other post too.